# How to run post build events after custom target?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have some commands in post build events that i cannot move to targets and i need the post build events to run after custom target that i created. I have custom target `CustomTarget`that depends on default target `Build`.

```
<Target Name="CustomTarget" DependsOnTargets="Build">
<!--Execute some commands-->
</Target>
```

i've changed default target in .csproj from `Build`to `CustomBuild`

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="CustomTarget" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<!--...-->
</Project>
```

And code from post build events is still executed before `CustomTarged`. Is there some way to execute post build events after all targets defined in `DefaultTargets=""` project section?

Comment: Hi, ToolsVersion="4.0"? what vs version or msbuild version do you use?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT i'm using vs 2019, but project was created in previous version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using script like:

```
  <Target Name="CustomTarget" BeforeTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <!--Execute some commands-->
    <Message Text="This is custom target"/>
  </Target>
```

According to the log:
The vs will execute custom target before post-build-event.

[image]

Comment: i'm using vs 2019. I need to execute CustomTarget before post build events, not after.

Comment: @ekvalizer Sorry I didn't notice. I've edited my answer, check if it's helpful:)